# radio button show values in combo box

Tags: java, mysql, if-statement, netbeans, radio-button

I confused with this if-else because I'm new in Java & MySQL and I tried to make it by myself.

```
public Menu() {
        initComponents();
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/restaurant", "root", "");
            System.out.println("ODBC Connection Successful");

            showCategory();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ODBC Connection Failed" + e);

        }
    }
```

if - else

```
private void showCategory() {
        try {
            Statement stmt;
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            if (rbMFood.isSelected()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menu_cat WHERE type_id = 'TY02'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                cmbMCat.addItem(rs.getString("menu_cat"));
            }

        } else {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM menu_cat WHERE type_id = 'TY01'");
            while (rs.next()) {
                cmbMCat.addItem(rs.getString("menu_cat"));
            }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Radio Button

```
private void rbMFoodActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        type = "Food";
    }                                       

    private void rbMDrinkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        type = "Drink";
    }
```

And I declare the function in the end of the program

```
private String type;
```

When I click drink / food, the category still drink's category.

[image]

The database

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well what debugging steps have you performed?

Comment: `type_id = TYO2` should be `type_id = 'TYO2'` and so for the other.

Comment: can you post your table definition please? it looks like youre having a column "menu_cat" inside your table "menu_cat", at least you are trying to access the value of that column

Comment: if you are new in Java, you should first learn the basics. A big improvement on the above code: turn this - catch (Exception e) {

        } into this: - catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
        }

In your current code, no matter what goes wrong, you'll never know, because you swallow the exception.

Comment: First try to debug and see, if your query is actually, returning appropriate values, if it works, you need to invoke the repaint method, which actually, refresh the section

Comment: It's really bad practice to have empty catch blocks. Insert `e.printStackTrace()` into it, and include the output in your post if an exception occurs.

Comment: Already! I made a typo hehe @AbhikChakraborty But when I click food, the category that drink's.

Comment: @enjeru who said that? you should at the very least log somehow that something is going wrong, or remove the try/catch block, so you'll notice when something's wrong.

Comment: Can you post the code where you have handled the `eventListeners` of the `RadioButton`?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean by that. anyway, with the code you have posted above, almost every exception possible could be thrown, disrupting the flow, but since you hide them, you 'll never know.

Comment: Ok But how is the `showCatagory()` called?

Comment: You may want to show more code for it to become more clear.

Comment: @Blip sorry, my internet really slowly. Look my coding. How? ^^

Comment: @Stultuske all coding?

Comment: All the relevant code.

Comment: @Stultuske I think all code above are relevant code. Can you see it? ^^

Comment: yes. but you don't show the declaration of the radioboxes, so we can't see whether or not you are checking on the right fields (for instance)

Comment: please check my corrected answer below and try to follow the suggestions given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `rs.getString("menu_cat")` But the format is `rs.getString(<Column Name>)` But you are using `rs.getString(<Table Name>)` As "menu_cat" is name of the table and not the name of the column.

**AFTER POSTING CONSTRUCTOR**

What I see from the code you have posted, is that You have called `showCategory()` in the constructor. This method is responsible for populating the `JComboBox` `cmbMCat`. Now the `cmbMCat` is being populated when you are creating the new `Menu`. After that the items list of the `cmbMCat` does not  change.

So, What I suggest is that you call the `showCategory()` from the `rbMFoodActionPerformed` and `rbMDrinkActionPerformed` methods. I hope this will solve your problem.

Also add `cmbMCat.removeAllItems()` before `Statement stmt;` to remove all the items that are there in the `cmbMCat` and reset it with a fresh list of items.

**After comment regarding the if-else**

Change the `showCatagory()` as below:

```
private void showCategory() {
        cmbMCat.removeAllItems();
        try {
            PreparedStatement stmt; //Used Prepared statement
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM menu_cat WHERE type_id = ?";
            stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            if (type.equals("Drink")) {
                stmt.setString("TY01");    
            } else {
                stmt.setString("TY02");
            }
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                while (rs.next()) {
                    cmbMCat.addItem(rs.getString("menu_cat"));
                }

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
```

Also note that you `eventListener` code should be:

```
private void rbMFoodActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                        
    type = "Food";
    showCategory();
}                                       

private void rbMDrinkActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){                                         
    type = "Drink";
    showCategory();
}
```

Comment: wait. My column & table name are same. Sorry make you confused ><

Comment: could you post your column names? Also a better query would be `SELECT menu_cat FROM menu_cat WHERE type_id = 'TYO2'`

Comment: Ah. So, `showCategory()` in constructor I delete it?

Comment: if you do not want to populate the `comboBox` initially then delete it else keep it

Comment: I already test it. Yeah. It's success. But when I click other (drink), the values still the last one (food).

Comment: @enjeru add `cmbMCat.removeAllItems()` before `Statement stmt;` and this will solve your problem

Comment: now the condition like before. when I click food and then drink, drink show nothing ;---;

Comment: @enjeru does clicking back to food after clicking drink, does the values show in `cmbMCat`?

Comment: yes. If clicking back, keep show the values. But when we click the new one, that show nothing. Ah when I click drink first, the category show empty.

Comment: @enjeru do you mean to say that when food is selected the values are showing and when drink is selected values are not showing? Secondly before you added `cmbMCat.removeAllItems()` before `Statement stmt;` the values were showing when drink was selected?

Comment: I think the problem in if else, because when I change TY01 / TY02 in if else,  the values in else statement didnt show anything. Help me please><

Comment: Ah it's done. I think I made an typo but I dunno where ._. I just copy if statement and paste it. hehe. Thank you very much for your help :)