# get data searching from radiobutton to combobox

Tags: java, swing, combobox, radio-button

I want to search an item, but I get troubled that radio button and combo box show nothing. If you want to get show combo box, radio button must get picked please. I confused what code that I must type for radio button. Can you help me?

```
private void txtSearchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        String menu_name = txtSearch.getText();

        Statement stmt;
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from menu WHERE menu_name like '%" + menu_name + "%' ");

        if (rs.next()) {
            txtMID.setText("" + rs.getString("menu_id"));

            cmbMCat.setSelectedItem("" + rs.getString("menu_cat")); //combo box
            txtMName.setText("" + rs.getString("menu_name"));
            txtMPrice.setText("" + rs.getString("menu_price"));

            //DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblMenu.getModel();
        //model.addRow(new Object[]{txtMID.getText(), type, cmbMCat.getSelectedItem(), txtMName.getText(), txtMPrice.getText()});
        } 
    }
    catch (SQLException | HeadlessException e) {

    }
}
```

[image]

avocado roll from database
[image]

category and type database

[image]

now, [image]

[image]

Comment: Does anything happen if you add `e.printStackTrace()` within your exception handler? It is bad practice to catch exceptions and do nothing about it.

Comment: netbeans wrote " `throwable.printStackTrace()` should be removed" ._.  @npinti

Comment: I think the problem is coding for radio button to set blabla. But I dunno what must I write there. Can you help me? this is my radio button -> [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30050836/if-else-function-using-radio-button-show-values-in-combo-box) @npinti

Comment: The `e.printStackTrace()` will print any exceptions you have to console. This is for debugging purposes and will not be part of the end product, thus for this case, you could ignore the warning shown by netbeans. However, you will need to eventually throw in a message box or something like that. If you get any exceptions printed out, please include them in your answer.

Comment: Already. But nothing happens @npinti

Comment: Then I think that the next step would be to check if the query returns anything. It might be that the query is passing but the result set is not returning anything.

Comment: Nah. That's what I mean. So, I think I must put code for radio button, but I dunno what code it is. What must I set? I tried search in google but I cant find anything. @npinti

Comment: I did a quick test and it seems that the `setSelectedItem` will work only on items which already exist in the combo box. If the item does not exist, the combo box will not change. Can you please ensure that the combo box is populated with items *before*? Also, if possible, please provide a sample value for `rs.getString("menu_cat")`.

Comment: Are you wanting to set one of the two radio buttons based on the return from the database call? If so, you need an if/else statement and call setSelected() on the proper radio button based on the data. (I would also put the buttons in a button group so that only one can be selected at a time). As for your combo box, have you created a model for it containing all of the expected possible values? When you call setSelectedItem(Object) on a combo box, if Object is not in the combo box model's list, it won't display anything.

Comment: I already tried it in Save Button, and It's work (combo box) @npinti

Comment: Can you code for me? Because I still confused how to make them. Please @swingMan

Comment: @enjeru: Take a look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) link. It should tell you how to group radio buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to write it like this:

```
try{

     for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
         combo.removeItemAt(0);
     }


     rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from menu_cat");

     int i = 0;
     String[] categories = new String[99];

     while(rs.next()){

         categories[i] = rs.getString("menu_cat");            
         i++;            
     }

     i = 0;

     while(!categories[i].equals("")){

          combo.addItem(categories[i]);
         i++;

     }

}catch (Exception e){

     System.out.println("Unimportant error: " + e);
}
```

So don't care about this error!

Comment: Where must I put it? Btw, I just looked your profile. I got excited u just 17th and have a job. I'm 19 :")

Comment: AH! IT'S WORKING! THANK YOU SO MUCH :) Waw. Happy for you, senior :p

Answer (score 1):

I would create two events, one on the radiobox "Food" and the other on the radiobox "Drink". I suppose, that you have the two radioboxes in one buttongroup.

```
private void radio_foodFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                       

    int itemCount = combo.getItemCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        combo.removeItemAt(0);
    }

    combo.addItem("Food Item 1");
    combo.addItem("Food Item 2");

}                                      

private void radio_drinkFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                        

    int itemCount = combo.getItemCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        combo.removeItemAt(0);
    }

    combo.addItem("Drink Item 1");
    combo.addItem("Drink Item 2");

}
```

So the result is now when you're clicking on the radiobox "Food" the fooditems appear in the combobox and if you are clicking on the radiobox "Drink" the drinkitems appear in the combobox.

[image]    [image]

Comment: ok. It's working but my question, when we type not selected. Can you help me? Please ><

Comment: what do you want in the ComboBox if no radiobox is selected?

Comment: No. What I mean in here is when I type Avocado Roll in search, the data about avocado roll show and radio button go to food and combo box go to sushi. Do you get it? ><

Comment: Yes, I try out a new solution!

Comment: One more question, where do you get the information whether Avocado Roll is a food?

Comment: In my database. Wait I'll upload it

Answer (score 1):

So second try, with this code it should work, it checks first the menu_typ and the application will decide between "Food" and "Drink". At the end the application set the selected item in your ComboBox to your menu_cat.

```
    if(rs.getString("menu_type").equals("Food")){

        radio_food.setSelected(true);
        radio_drink.setSelected(false);

    }else if(rs.getString("menu_type").equals("Drink")){

        radio_drink.setSelected(true);
        radio_food.setSelected(false);

    }else{

        System.out.println("No valid menu type");

    }

    combo.setSelectedItem(rs.getString("menu_cat"));
```

I hope I have helped you!

Comment: Yes, you have to set all the values to your combobox! 
        `combo.addItem("Tea");
        combo.addItem("Soda");
        combo.addItem("Sashimi");
        combo.addItem("Sushi");
        // Add all menu_cat like this`

Comment: So, I add it manually? How about I want to add more category in database? So, I must add in here too? hehe ><

Comment: So, how? Ah. `combo.addItem("Tea"); ` How I put it?

Comment: Yes, in the end. But first you have to get all different menu_cat. I'm trying to figure out the algorithm for it. So I will post the solution for it! The goal is when you add a new menu_cat in your DB that this menu_cat is automatically appears in the ComboBox.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Yes, I know but you have to write a statement that returns all different menu_cat from your DB. So you can take all this different menu_cat and put them in your ComboBox, do you know what I mean?

Comment: No, I don't get it ._. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

For filling your ComboBox you need to execute a new query first, this query gives you all different menu_cat back. First you need to delete the existing entries in the ComboBox.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
        combo.removeItemAt(0);
    }


    rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from menu_cat");

    int i = 0;
    String[] categories = new String[99];

    while(rs.next()){

        categories[i] = rs.getString("menu_cat");            
        i++;            
    }

    i = 0;

    while(!categories[i].equals("")){

        combo.addItem(categories[i]);
        i++;

    }
```

This code does the following steps:

- Delete all entries in your ComboBox
- Execute a new query
- Save the all values in an array
- Add all items in the array to your ComboBox

Comment: Can I ask? Where I put this coding? hehe. In radio button focusgained ? hehe

Comment: I would put this code to your search action, after the user has clicked the search button. I would put it at the end of the code that you had posted in your question!

Comment: ah. It's show the category BUT :( stuck in first category. Don't change to what must they go.

Comment: look above. Half of data show nothing and get errors ._.)a

Comment: can you post a screenshot of the data in the combobox?

Comment: How? Am i make you confused? Sorry ><

Comment: I can't access to the db so it's very difficult for me to see the issue, if you could post a screenshot of the entries in the ComboBox I would be very happy, because then I can delimit the problem. How I can see the ComboBox isn't empty, is that true?

Comment: Ah yes hehe. I think I already post it. Entries for comboBox is menu_cat. Did it what you want? ><

Comment: Yes but, I would like to see what's actually in your GUI combobox. I would like to have a screenshot of the unfolded combobox in your GUI.

Comment: It is that what you want? ._.)a

Comment: Yes, the data are complete! This are all the entries from the db! Now we have just to catch this error. Surround the block for filling the ComboBox with a try & catch - statement. The reason for this error is, that the last array entry is null so the application want to put null into the ComboBox what is not possible.

Comment: Ah I see. So what must I do? >< hehe